# How to check if file has been added in this dropzone.js bootstrap example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

The input file type has been styled into a button. What I do not understand is how to grab the file input to check if it has been added or not.

**Dropzone config**

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".container", { // Make the whole body a dropzone
  url: "/images-save", // Set the url
  thumbnailWidth: 80,
  thumbnailHeight: 80,
  parallelUploads: 20,
  previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
  maxFilesize: 255,
  maxFiles: 1,
  autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
  previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
  clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
  acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.jpeg",
  dictFileTooBig:"image file exceeds ----", 
  autoProcessQueue: false,
});
```

**Dropzone.js Bootstrap**

```
  <div id="actions" class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-7">

        <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button dz-clickable">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Add files...</span>
        </span>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start" >
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
            <span>Start upload</span>
        </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
            <span>Cancel upload</span>
        </button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

For example a normal input form would be like this:

```
<input type="file" id="inputfile">
```

I would go do this to check:

```
if(document.getElementById("inputfile").value != "") {
   // checking if there is a file added
}
```

So how can I do that with the dropzone.js bootstrap?

Comment: did you read the doc ? https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events

Answer (score 1):

Dropzone has an event called "addedFile"

You can read more about the events it supports in this [documentation](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events).

```js
// The recommended way from within the init configuration:
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) { alert("Added file."); });
  }
};
```

This code might work for you:

```js
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".container", { // Make the whole body a dropzone
  url: "/images-save", // Set the url
  thumbnailWidth: 80,
  thumbnailHeight: 80,
  parallelUploads: 20,
  previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
  maxFilesize: 255,
  maxFiles: 1,
  autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
  previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
  clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
  acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.jpeg",
  dictFileTooBig:"image file exceeds ----", 
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) { alert("Added file."); });
  }
});
```